# C program else clause occurring when it shouldn't

Tags: c, while-loop

So I am new to C(Java programmer) and I'm unsure of why this situation is occurring.

I am simulating a vending machine and the user is supposed to input a single char to the terminal which acts as coins. Here is the code to better explain:

```
while(leftOverCost > 0){
  printf("Enter coin(nqrd): ");
  char coin;
  coin = getchar();
  if(coin=='N' || coin=='n'){
    printf("Nickle detected.\n");
    userTotal += 5;
    leftOverCost -= 5;
    printf("\tYou have inserted a total of %d cents.\n", userTotal);
    if(leftOverCost < 0) break;
    printf("\tPlease insert %d more cents.\n", leftOverCost);
  }
  else if(coin=='D' || coin=='d'){
    printf("Dime detected.\n");
    userTotal += 10;
    leftOverCost -= 10;
    printf("\tYou have inserted a total of %d cents.\n", userTotal);
    if(leftOverCost < 0) break;
    printf("\tPlease insert %d more cents.\n", leftOverCost);
  }
  else if(coin=='Q' || coin=='q'){
    printf("Quarter detected.\n");
    leftOverCost -= 25;
    userTotal += 25;
    printf("\tYou have inserted a total of %d cents.\n", userTotal);
    if(leftOverCost < 0) break;
    printf("\tPlease insert %d more cents.\n", leftOverCost);
  }
  else if(coin=='R' || coin=='r'){
    printf("bye\n");
    break;
  }
  else{
    printf("Unknown coin.");
  }
}
```

Why does this else clause always execute? I get output in the form:

```
    You have inserted a total of 25 cents.
        Please insert 30 more cents.
Enter coin (nqrd): Unknown coin rejected.
```

Shouldn't it only execute when the user inputs something that my code does not recognize? Is this something to do with the getchar() method? It occurs twice when I put in unrecognized chars.

Comment: Which character do you get? You get error after hitting Enter or something else...

Comment: So it recognizes enter as a char? Would I be better off working with strings or maybe storing the user input as an integer perhaps? 

(I suppose starting off with Java made me used to the high level)

Comment: Have you tried to determine what character the program thinks you entered?

Comment: you can try to do `scanf` from `stdin`

Comment: Where is the word "rejected" in sentence "unknown coin rejected" in your code? Is the the last message, may you please provide the input chars(coins) with the result you have added to your question?

Comment: Please do not downvote without giving a reason. You are preventing this site from accelerating growth when you do not give reason for downvoting and shower beginners with downvotes.

This is a terrible trend that occurs far too often on stackoverflow - it needs to stop. It is unconstructive.

Comment: Most people downvote for the reason because the user made such an easy mistake. It has happened before with me in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard function `getchar` reads all characters including white space characters.

Instead use the function `scanf`

```
scanf( " %c", coin );
```

or

```
if ( scanf( " %c", coin ) == 1 )
{
    //...
```

Comment: that is still good, but the user still has more problems in the code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscosw I don't understand what you mean? I don't understand what I did wrong?

Comment: @narusin It is your problem whether you have understood or not. It does not bother me.

Comment: what did I do wrong that is getting you mad? If there is something, please tell me. I won't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

In C.

The else is executing because of the "\n" or "enter" command after you have entered your char.

You can solve it like this:

```
while(leftOverCost > 0) {
                printf("Enter coin(nqrd): ");
                char coin;
                coin = getchar();
                if(coin=='N' || coin=='n') {
                        printf("Nickle detected.\n");
                        userTotal += 5;
                        leftOverCost -= 5;
                        printf("\tYou have inserted a total of %d cents.\n", userTotal);

                        if(leftOverCost < 0)
                                break;
                        printf("\tPlease insert %d more cents.\n", leftOverCost);
                }
                else if(coin=='D' || coin=='d') {
                        printf("Dime detected.\n");
                        userTotal += 10;
                        leftOverCost -= 10;
                        printf("\tYou have inserted a total of %d cents.\n", userTotal);

                        if(leftOverCost < 0)
                                break;
                        printf("\tPlease insert %d more cents.\n", leftOverCost);

                }
                else if(coin=='Q' || coin=='q') {
                        printf("Quarter detected.\n");
                        leftOverCost -= 25;
                        userTotal += 25;
                        printf("\tYou have inserted a total of %d cents.\n", userTotal);

                        if(leftOverCost < 0)
                                break;
                        printf("\tPlease insert %d more cents.\n", leftOverCost);

                }
                else if(coin=='R' || coin=='r') {
                        printf("bye\n");
                        break;
                }
             /// IMPORTAN HERE
               else if(coin == '\n') {
                ; 
                // means do nothing. This is the naiv solution
                }
                else {
                printf("Unknown coin.");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time, but I have the solution to your problem. The problem in your code is the `break`. I found it a bit bizarre that you would put `break` in an `if/else` statement. We usually use `break` to break out of a loop. If you get rid of that and fix the inner `if` statement, that should solve most of your problem. The next problem was `getchar()`. That isn't a good idea to use in your code, so you should have tried `scanf` code. It's a lot easier that way. Also, add a `printf` and `scanf` statement in the beginning for the `leftOverCost`because it isn't set.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

  float leftOverCost = 345; //Remove '= 345' and add a printf and scanf statement to set the cost.
  float userTotal;
  while(leftOverCost > 0) {
                printf("Enter coin(nqrd): ");
                char coin;
                scanf(" %c", &coin);
                if(coin=='N' || coin=='n') {
                        printf("Nickle detected.\n");
                        userTotal += 0.05;
                        leftOverCost -= 0.05;
                        printf("\tYou have inserted a total of %f cents.\n", userTotal);
                        printf("%f", leftOverCost);

                        if(leftOverCost > 0){
                        printf("\tPlease insert %f more cents.\n", leftOverCost);
                        }
                }
                else if(coin=='D' || coin=='d') {
                        printf("Dime detected.\n");
                        userTotal += 0.10;
                        leftOverCost -= 0.10;
                        printf("\tYou have inserted a total of %f cents.\n", userTotal);

                        if(leftOverCost > 0){
                        printf("\tPlease insert %f more cents.\n", leftOverCost);
                        }

                }
                else if(coin=='Q' || coin=='q') {
                        printf("Quarter detected.\n");
                        leftOverCost -= 0.25;
                        userTotal += 0.25;
                        printf("\tYou have inserted a total of %f cents.\n", userTotal);

                        if(leftOverCost > 0){
                        printf("\tPlease insert %f more cents.\n", leftOverCost);
                        }

                }
                else if(coin=='R' || coin=='r') {
                        printf("bye\n");
                }
                else {
                printf("Unknown coin.");
                }
}
}
```

P.S, I changed up the code a bit to make more decimal like money. A quarter is 0.25 cents. You get what I mean. I'm using `float` to only hold decimal. Also, add some `if` statement to see if the `leftOverCost` is less than zero, it will give the drink and give any change back.